# UnicodeDecodeError using pdf2txt

Tags: ubuntu, extract, tex

I'm using pdf2txt (pdfminer python tool) in ubuntu to extract text from some Norwegian pdf's.

This tool works perfectly with some of the pdf's im using, and i get the extracted text in a .txt file, but half of the pdf's, more or less, throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/bin/pdf2txt", line 101, in module
>      if **name** == '**main**': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>
> File "/usr/bin/pdf2txt", line 95, in main
>      caching=caching, check_extractable=True)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 832, in process_pdf
>      interpreter.process_page(page)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 757, in process_page
>      self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 770, in render_contents
>      self.execute(list_value(streams))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 795, in execute
>      func(*args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 605, in do_BDC
>      self.device.begin_tag(tag, props)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfdevice.py", line 160, in begin_tag
>      in sorted(props.iteritems()) )
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/pdfdevice.py", line 159, in 
>      s = ''.join( ' %s="%s"' % (enc(k), enc(str(v))) for (k,v)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer/utils.py", line 164, in enc
>      return x.encode(codec, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I would understand that any of them work, or all of them work, but they are all in Norweigan, so they are using the same characters. Why would some of them work and some of them not?

There are even some pdf's that throws this error when i try to extract the text just from page 1, and it works good extracting the text from page 2.

Here is the command i'm using:

pdf2txt -t tag -p 4 -A -o out/route/tag.txt in/route/405448.pdf

And here you have two examples of the pdf's im using.

```
This one works perrfectly for me: http://54.171.169.37/tilbud/pdf/magazines/404707/404707.pdf

This one dosen't work in any page: http://54.171.169.37/tilbud/pdf/magazines/404635/404635.pdf 

And this one, just works in some pages : http://54.171.169.37/tilbud/pdf/magazines/401944/401944.pdf
```

Any idea of what is happening?
TY in advance

EDIT:
I've realize that, if i extract the text in normal mode and not in tag mode (pdf2txt -t tag) it works on the pages it didn't work before. So is a problem with "tag" type of extraction.

Comment: Unfortunately PDF files become more and more different in version, format and generated by different software. From many of them is impossible to extract clear text - they are "ready for view" or "print".

Comment: I understand that, but ¿how comes that the last pdf i added here, does work on pages 3 and 5 and dosen't work on pages 1,2 and 4?
It must be another kind of problem.

Comment: Maybe simple incompatibility or bug in pdf2txt. Have you tried another pdf extractor? http://www.a-pdf.com/text/

Comment: I tried tesseract and 2 or 3 more which i don't remember their names, but pdf2txt was the best. (at that point of course).